# Changing view for selected in view-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

How do I change the view for the selected row when using a view-based `NSTableView`? Specifically, I'd like to have a simple NSView subclass for unselected rows and a more complex NSView subclass for the selected row which allows editing of more information associated with the row item.

An example is the way Things allows you to expand the item being edited as seen here: http://culturedcode.com/things/

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you want to use a different NSTableCellView subclass when the row is selected. I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTableView *table = [notification object];
    NSIndexSet *allColumns = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[table tableColumns] count])];
    [table reloadDataForRowIndexes:[table selectedRowIndexes] columnIndexes:allColumns];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    if ([[tableView selectedRowIndexes] containsIndex:row])
    {
        // If the row is selected, return an instance of the class for selected views
        SelectedTableCellView *selectedView = ...; // Get from makeViewWithIdentifier:
        // Set up selectedView
        return selectedView;
    }
    else 
    {
        NonSelectedTableCellView *nonSelectedView = ...; // Get from makeViewWithIdentifier:
        // Set up nonSelectedView
        return nonSelectedView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if NSTableView is implemented with Cocoa Bindings ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be nice if you elaborated a little bit more on what you mean by "change the view to a more complex view"

Nonetheless, you could for instance, implement `- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification` in the delegate of the table view, get the selected `NSTableRowView` if it is visible, and change it in what way you want, which includes making it more complex, expanding it (see below), etc.

To modify the size of a row, you would need to implement `- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row` in the same delegate, and call the table view's `-noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged` to update the height for particular rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the app is created by `NSOutlineView` in outlineview only you can easily expand your selected row...

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{        


    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) 
    {
        return YES;        
    }else 
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I think this way is write..